# Groovy script to retrieve all successful Jenkins builds from one specific job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to write a Groovy script to retrieve all successful builds from one specific Jenkins job. Here's what I have written:

```
import hudson.model.*;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;

def jobName = "my_folder/my_job";
def passedBuilds = [''];

try {
    def job_data = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
    job_data.builds.each {
        def build = it
        if(it.getResult().toString().equals("SUCCESS")) {
            it.badgeActions.each {
                passedBuilds.add(build.displayName[1..-1])
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    passedBuilds.add(e);
}
    return passedBuilds;
```

Unfortunately the script does not work as expected and leaves the `passedBuilds` list empty. What did I do wrong?

Note: The Groovy script did not run in a Groovy Sandbox because the `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName()` method requires elevated rights. The `add()` statement in the `catch` section of `try-catch` is for my own purposes to see possible error messages, because I don't have access to the actual Jenkins errors.

Comment: Are you using "System Groovy? You need to in order to access Jenkins job data: [Groovy Script vs System Groovy Script](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/)

Comment: @IanW I'm using this script to create a drop-down menu for a parametrized build. I'm not sure if the script is running on master's JVM.

Comment: @IanW did you find any other mistakes in the script that could cause it not to work?

Comment: Running from the the Groovy console ( `${JENKINS_URL}/script` }, it works fine. Can't test the rest for you.

Comment: Thank you for checking, I was able to verify that the script itself works - I just need to get it to do what I want to. The above job called `jobName` has a build parameter called "VERSION", I want to access it and add it to the `passedBuilds` list, do you know how I can manage that?